# In my Kafka Topic, End-of-the-Offset is higher than last messages's Offset number, because of this i can see the consumer lag 1

Tags: apache-kafka

Using a Kafka Stream Application I am reading messages from input-topic and publishing to the Output-topic.

But in my Output-topic, the last message Offset value is "18" but End-Of-The-Offset value is "20"

```
Topic test.topic.out[33], offset: 17, key: 228, payload: 1003 bytes: {"ITEM_LOC_CHG_ID":4657706,"sku_selling_location_id":"17960858808","selling_location_id":"7619017","event_type":"P","store_number":"228","sku":"7734279","location_indicator":"1","capacity":"0.0","width":"0.0","last_update_userid":"sslpromospaceupdate1","sku_selling_location_change_date":"2019-12-17 13:08:49.0","ticket_processed":"N","store_item_shelf_sequence":null,"store_section_short_name":null,"mezzanine":null,"store_aisle_id_nearest":null,"store_segment_number_actual":null,"store_aisle_id":null,"store_reference_bay_id":null,"store_logical_bay_id":null,"store_shelf_id":null,"store_plinth_id":null,"online_processed":"N","item_loc_chg_txn_id":"402141004","sub_category":"330","default_pack_size":"4.0","selling_location_type":"0","product_sequence_within_subcat":"11","old_capacity":null,"old_width":null,"old_store_aisle_id":null,"old_store_logical_bay_id":null,"old_store_shelf_id":null,"old_store_item_shelf_sequence":null,"old_product_sequence_within_subcat":null,"COPY_TIME":1576588219061}

Topic test.topic.out[33], offset: 18, key: 228, payload: 1003 bytes: {"ITEM_LOC_CHG_ID":4657707,"sku_selling_location_id":"17960858809","selling_location_id":"7619017","event_type":"P","store_number":"228","sku":"7860138","location_indicator":"1","capacity":"0.0","width":"0.0","last_update_userid":"sslpromospaceupdate1","sku_selling_location_change_date":"2019-12-17 13:08:49.0","ticket_processed":"N","store_item_shelf_sequence":null,"store_section_short_name":null,"mezzanine":null,"store_aisle_id_nearest":null,"store_segment_number_actual":null,"store_aisle_id":null,"store_reference_bay_id":null,"store_logical_bay_id":null,"store_shelf_id":null,"store_plinth_id":null,"online_processed":"N","item_loc_chg_txn_id":"402141005","sub_category":"330","default_pack_size":"6.0","selling_location_type":"0","product_sequence_within_subcat":"12","old_capacity":null,"old_width":null,"old_store_aisle_id":null,"old_store_logical_bay_id":null,"old_store_shelf_id":null,"old_store_item_shelf_sequence":null,"old_product_sequence_within_subcat":null,"COPY_TIME":1576588219061}
% Reached end of topic test.topic.out [33] at offset 20: exiting
```

due to this my consumer-lag always showing 1(even though my consumer service consumed all the messages from the partition).

what might be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Please show the command you're using... And is this a compact topic?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using transactional semantics in your producer.
When your producer uses transactions, kafka generates "**control batches**"

> A control batch contains a single record called the control record. Control records should not be passed on to applications. Instead, they are used by consumers to filter out aborted transactional messages.

Check official doc: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#controlbatch